# React fucntional component state issue

Tags: reactjs

Been stuck on this. I'm trying to make a simple date and time clock using React functional components. I've also added a switch that should turn the date on and off, but right now it doesn't work. I've been trying to work with material-ui, which is currently very confusing and I thought that the onChange property on switch wasn't working, but I see that the state is not working as well. The checked is set as true, therefore, the date should not be displayed, but it is not so. I'll appreciate if anyone can find some small and obvious mistake that I'm missing.

```
import React from 'react';
import './Time.css';
import Clock from "react-live-clock";
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch';

function Time() {
  const [checked, setStatus] = React.useState(true);
  const today = new Date(),
  date = `${today.toDateString()}`;
  const style = {
    display: "none"
  };
  const none = {};
  return (
    <div className="all-time">
    <FormControlLabel
        control={
          <Switch
            onChange={() => setStatus(!checked)}
            name="checked"
            color="primary"
          />
        }
      />
    <div className="clock">
        <Clock className="time" date={""} format={"HH:mm:ss"} ticking={true} timezone={"Europe/Vilnius"} />
        <h1 className="date" style={checked === true ? {style} : {none}}>{date}</h1>
    </div></div>
  )
}

export default Time;
```

Comment: maybe adding the ```display:'inline-block'``` or something inside ```none``` helps

Comment: and you might want to change it like this : ```{checked?style:none}```

Comment: Huh, that actually solved it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the value to the switch

```
<Switch
  value={checked}
  onChange={() => setStatus(!checked)}
  name="checked"
  color="primary"
/>
```